# Import a library only on the server side to use in getInitialProps

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js, server-side-rendering

### My setup

I'm using `getInitialProps` on the `_app.js` file to preload data on the server side:

```
import App from "next/app";

// The problematic import
import nodeFetchCache from "node-fetch-cache";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps, customProps }) {
  return <Component customProps={customProps} {...pageProps} />;
}

MyApp.getInitialProps = async (appContext) => {
  const appProps = await App.getInitialProps(appContext);
  
  // When I remove the top import and use a classic "fetch" here, it works fine
  const res = await nodeFetchCache(
    `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/api/node/last_items`
  );

  const items = await res.json();

  return {
    ...appProps,
    customProps: {
      footerArticles: items.data.articles,
      footerVideos: items.data.videos,
    },
  };
};

export default MyApp;
```

### My problem

This code yields an error:

> Unhandled Runtime Error TypeError: The "original" argument must be of
> type Function
>
> Call Stack promisify node_modules/util/util.js (614:0) eval
> node_modules/@npmcli/move-file/index.js (25:0)
> Object../node_modules/@npmcli/move-file/index.js
> file:///Users/dev/app/.next/static/chunks/pages/_app.js (716:1)
> Object.options.factory /_next/static/chunks/webpack.js (685:31)
> **webpack_require** file:///Users/dev/app/.next/static/chunks/webpack.js (37:33) fn
> /_next/static/chunks/webpack.js (354:21) eval
> node_modules/cacache/lib/entry-index.js (16:17)
> Object../node_modules/cacache/lib/entry-index.js
> file:///Users/dev/app/.next/static/chunks/pages/_app.js (1598:1)
> Object.options.factory /_next/static/chunks/webpack.js (685:31)
> **webpack_require** file:///Users/dev/app/.next/static/chunks/webpack.js (37:33) fn
> /_next/static/chunks/webpack.js (354:21) eval
> node_modules/cacache/ls.js (3:14) Object../node_modules/cacache/ls.js
> file:///Users/dev/app/.next/static/chunks/pages/_app.js (1686:1)
> Object.options.factory /_next/static/chunks/webpack.js (685:31)
> **webpack_require** file:///Users/dev/app/.next/static/chunks/webpack.js (37:33) fn
> /_next/static/chunks/webpack.js (354:21) eval
> node_modules/cacache/index.js (3:11)
> Object../node_modules/cacache/index.js
> file:///Users/dev/app/.next/static/chunks/pages/_app.js (1543:1)
> Object.options.factory /_next/static/chunks/webpack.js (685:31)
> **webpack_require** file:///Users/dev/app/.next/static/chunks/webpack.js (37:33) fn
> /_next/static/chunks/webpack.js (354:21) eval
> webpack-internal:///./node_modules/node-fetch-cache/src/classes/caching/file_system_cache.js
> (5:65)
> Module../node_modules/node-fetch-cache/src/classes/caching/file_system_cache.js
> file:///Users/dev/app/.next/static/chunks/pages/_app.js (4513:1)
> Module.options.factory /_next/static/chunks/webpack.js (685:31)
> **webpack_require** file:///Users/dev/app/.next/static/chunks/webpack.js (37:33) fn
> /_next/static/chunks/webpack.js (354:21) eval
> webpack-internal:///./node_modules/node-fetch-cache/src/index.js
> (13:95) Module../node_modules/node-fetch-cache/src/index.js
> file:///Users/dev/app/.next/static/chunks/pages/_app.js (4557:1)
> Module.options.factory /_next/static/chunks/webpack.js (685:31)
> **webpack_require** file:///Users/dev/app/.next/static/chunks/webpack.js (37:33) fn
> /_next/static/chunks/webpack.js (354:21) eval
> webpack-internal:///./pages/_app.js (10:74) Module../pages/_app.js
> file:///Users/dev/app/.next/static/chunks/pages/_app.js (40:1)
> Module.options.factory /_next/static/chunks/webpack.js (685:31)
> **webpack_require** file:///Users/dev/app/.next/static/chunks/webpack.js (37:33) fn
> /_next/static/chunks/webpack.js (354:21) eval
> node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/next-client-pages-loader.js?page=%2F_app&absolutePagePath=private-next-pages%2F_app!
> (5:15) eval node_modules/next/dist/client/route-loader.js (207:48)

From what other devs told me, it seems like Next is trying to import server side code on the client. Even when I remove the `await nodeFetchCache(...)` call, the only fact that I import `'node-fetch-cache'` at the top gives me an error.

### My question

Is what I'm trying to achieve even possible ? Isn't `getInitialProps` supposed to run only on the server side? And isn't code/tree shaking supposed to eliminate unused imports from the client side bundle?

I'm a bit lost here. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I would try using fetch in your getInitialProps and make a proxy-call to an api route instead. Inside of your api route, it should be possible to import the package.

Answer (score 2):

> Isn't `getInitialProps` supposed to run only on the server side?

Only in certain conditions.

Usually, `getInitialProps` runs both on the server (on initial page loads) and on the client (on client-side navigations). The exception to this rule is when the page you're navigating to uses `getServerSideProps`.

From the [`getInitialProps`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-initial-props) documentation:

> For the initial page load, `getInitialProps` will run on the server
> only. `getInitialProps` will then run on the client when navigating to a
> different route via the `next/link` component or by using `next/router`.
> However, if `getInitialProps` is used in a custom `_app.js`, and the page
> being navigated to implements `getServerSideProps`, then `getInitialProps`
> will run on the server.

As a consequence, unlike `getServerSideProps`/`getStaticProps`, `getInitialProps`'s code does not get [automatically eliminated](https://next-code-elimination.vercel.app/) from the client-side bundle by Next.js. This means that webpack will include any libraries you use inside `getInitialProps` in the client-side bundle. Ideally, you'll want to write isomorphic code in `getInitialProps` - code that can run both on the client and on the server.

---

In your case, `node-fetch-cache` is a Node.js library that cannot run in the browser. From what I can see the possible solutions are:

##### #1 Use an isomorphic package

The straightforward solution would be to use an isomorphic library to replace `node-fetch-cache`, like [`isomorphic-fetch`](https://github.com/matthew-andrews/isomorphic-fetch). This would allow you to use it both on the client and the server without the additional hassle.

##### #2 Use webpack's `IgnorePlugin`

If you want to run the `node-fetch-cache` code on the server only inside `getInitialProps`, you could use webpack's `IgnorePlugin` to ignore the module on the client-side, preventing any potential error.

```js
// next.config.js
module.exports = {
    // Other configs you may have...
    webpack: function (config, { isServer, webpack }) {
        if (!isServer) {
            config.plugins.push(
                new webpack.IgnorePlugin({ resourceRegExp: /node-fetch-cache/ })
            );
        }
        return config;
    }
}
```

##### #3 Use webpack's `resolve.alias`

Similar to the previous solution, you could use set `resolve.alias` to `false` to tell webpack to ignore `node-fetch-cache` on the client-side.

```js
// next.config.js
module.exports = {
    // Other configs you may have...
    webpack: function (config) {
        config.resolve.alias['node-fetch-cache'] = false;
        return config;
    }
}
```

Note that, for solutions **#2** and **#3** you need to refactor your current code to properly handle the client-side scenario, as `node-fetch-cache` won't be available to use there.

```js
MyApp.getInitialProps = async (appContext) => {
    const appProps = await App.getInitialProps(appContext);
  
    if (appContext.ctx.req) { // Check if on the server-side
        // Dynamically import `node-fetch-cache` on the server-only  
        const { default: nodeFetchCache } = await import('node-fetch-cache');
        const res = await nodeFetchCache(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/api/node/last_items`);
        const items = await res.json();

        return {
            ...appProps,
            customProps: {
                footerArticles: items.data.articles,
                footerVideos: items.data.videos
            }
        };
    } else {
        // Handle client-side here
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add this param to `package.json`

```
  "browser": {
    "node-fetch-cache": false
  }
```

so it will exclude it from the client-side bundling