# Dead code elimination for client in async getInitialProps in Next.js 12

Tags: next.js, webpack-5

I [thought](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59562136/214446) checking for `if (typeof window === 'undefined')` would remove the if clause and its contents in a Next.js production [build in the client bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61611405/how-to-best-import-server-only-code-in-next-js)? Has this been changed somehow in Next.js 11 or 12 or Webpack 5?

The [next-code-elimination tool doesn't do it](https://next-code-elimination.vercel.app/s/NXukiBnKY), but perhaps that tool is just not supporting `getInitialProps` anymore, only `getServerSideProps`? Or is the actual production build also not supporting dead code elimination in `getInitialProps` anymore?

Any pointers appreciated... (I found [this bug report](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/8086) but it's pretty old and closed, and the 2017 blog post [SSR and Server Only Modules](https://arunoda.me/blog/ssr-and-server-only-modules), which doesn't mention `typeof window` checking).

Minimal reproducible example:

```jsx
export const Content = () => {
  return <h1>hello</h1>
}

Content.getInitialProps = async () => {
  if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
    const article = await 'foo'
    return 'server'
  }
}
```

The problem seems to be the `await`  keyword! But even if I move the async stuff out to a helper function and don't use `await` inside `getInitialProps`, if the helper function contains moderately complex code, webpack seems to inline it and we're back to step one.

Comment: Only `getServerSideProps`/`getStaticProps`'s code is eliminated from the client bundle, as they are fully server-side code. `getInitialProps` code runs both on the client and server, and as such Next.js code elimination isn't applied to it. See slightly related question: [Import a library only on the server side to use in getInitialProps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71229074/1870780).

Comment: My experiments showed that some code is actually removed in getInitialProps as well (e.g. non-async code wrapped in `if (typeof window === 'undefined')` for example). I think I managed to solve my issue by using a dynamic import (`const myModule = await import('mymodule')`) inside that `if` block. This causes webpack to break that module out in its own chunk. The chunk is still generated for the client, but never actually loaded.